# Using DSL and DSLR in OptaPlanner

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I am newbie working on the NQueens example in OptaPlanner.
In the nQueensSolverConfig.xml file there is a scoreDrl tag where I can put my DRL file.

Now I am interested in using DSL and DSLR files instead of the DRL file so the rules will look more like natural language.

I tried creating a scoreDsl, dslr and dsl tag in the config file but no luck.

How can this be done?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<scoreDsl>` is not (yet) available, as there's no field for it on `ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.java`.

I believe that if you specify a DSL resource in `<scoreDrl>` in 6.2, it would actually work (yes, I realize that's semantically incorrect), because it ends up calling this code: `kieFileSystem.write(kieResources.newClassPathResource(scoreDrl, "UTF-8"));` so any KIE resource would be accepted actually.

Alternatively, build your own `KieBase` first and use `ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.setKieBase()`.